# Is my use of "oblivious" wrong?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, word-order

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308327/this-edit-was-intended-to-address-the-author?cb=1) on stackoverlow today and a couple of people have taken me to task over the use of the word "oblivious" in this sentence:

> I have deliberately omitted @ referencing the author of the comment,
>   but his standing in this community is not oblivious to me

I am trying to say that I am aware of his standing in the community.

It may be clunky, but is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. you want 'obvious'. 'Obvious' means clear. 'Oblivious' means unconscious. It does not really fit semantically in that sentence.

Comment: @Mitch - 'obvious' wouldn't fit in that context. I think 'oblivious' is the right word but it needs to be used in the correct way.

Comment: You need to tell us what you want it to mean. For example, it would be correct to say, "I am not oblivious to his standing in this community."

Comment: @chasly Thank you; I have updated my question with my intent.  It seems to me while your suggestion is easier on the ear and, therefore, easier to understand, semantically my original sentence wasn't "wrong".

Comment: Yes, you might be "oblivious", but a "standing" (which is inanimate) isn't.

Comment: ah, thanks @HotLicks - the penny drops with your comment!

Comment: His standing is not *unknown* to you.

Comment: As Hot Licks says, it is wrong.  You cannot use 'oblivious' that way. I think you need a different word.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I like the way you reworded it using "oblivious" and have edited my question on SO to reflect your suggestion, so, if you would like to make it the answer I will accept.

Comment: but props and thanks to @HotLicks too!

Comment: You could have kept "oblivious" if you'd reworked the sentence a bit, "I have deliberately omitted @ referencing the author of the comment, but I'm not oblivious to his standing in this community."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have deliberately omitted @ referencing the author of the comment,
>   but his standing in this community is not oblivious to me.
>
> I am trying to say that I am aware of his standing in the community.

In that case you are using the wrong word. Here's a possibility:

*His standing in this community is not unknown to me.*

or

*His standing in this community is not unfamiliar to me.*

P.S.

If you still wish to use the word *oblivious* then you could say,  "I am not oblivious to his standing in this community."   A person can be oblivious but an inanimate object or an abstract entity cannot.

Comment: Those are good alternatives. However, you might consider adding [your first suggestion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281125/is-my-use-of-oblivious-wrong#comment623417_281125) as well, to demonstrate how you might use the word in question ie "oblivious".